# max-width img not working on responsive

Tags: html, css

Does someone know a solution how to get the max-width on an img working?

https://jsfiddle.net/16601v4s/

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="cell-content">
        hier komt de tekst met één of meer afbeeldingen<br>
         <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/3/4/8/122620237858385735ivak_TV_Test_Screen.svg" width="800" border="0" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.row {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:table-row;
}
.cell-content {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 1%;
}
.cell-content img {
    max-width: 90% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: have you tried giving `display: block` ? btw, the jsfiddle works fine here.. you are limiting the `width` .

Comment: how do you need the output, there is no responsive code btw I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set width of parent container width in `%` instead of `px` like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/16601v4s/1/)**

```
.cell-content {   
    width: 50% !important;
    margin: 1%;
}
.cell-content img {
    max-width: 90% !important;
    height: auto !important;   
}
```

or try like this with `media query` **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/16601v4s/2/)**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .cell-content {
    width: 90% !important;

}
```

Comment: thnx :) only !important was enought (for ios not testen on android).

Answer (score 0):

You have (on your js fiddle, not the code above)

```
.cell-content {
 width: 100px;
 margin: 1%;
}
```

Change that to

```
.cell-content {
 width: 100%; //Or whatever width you need
 margin: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Max-width for images depends on parent container. Just remove the parent container width

```
.cell-content { margin: 1%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working Fine

`.cell-content` has the width reduced to `100px`

and

`.cell-content img` `max-width` which tries to inherit the parents with nothing but `100px` and used its `90%` which is `90px`

> So if you need to make the width bigger for the `img` don't set width for it's parent